# mysql join on same table and column names

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `profile_data`, structured like this:

```
id, user_id, field_id, value
```

I need to get user_id for any users that have a match one of several zipcodes and their country is United States.

So far I have this non-working query:

```
SELECT data1.user_id 
  FROM profile_data data1, profile_data data2 
 WHERE data1.field_id = 80
   AND ( value = '94114' OR value = '94146' OR value = '94117' )
   AND data2.field_id = 90
   AND value = 'United States'
```

Comment: Have you considered the IN clause?

Comment: your query makes no sense, how is this a join? What is it exactly that you are searching for? You need to rephrase what the result of this SQL should be

Comment: Why do you have profile_data twice in your from statement? Do profile_data relate to each other in some way? (Employee - manager for example) Since there is no distinguishing relation between the two instances of profile data, your result set is going to be... ugly.

Comment: @stevebot - I thought IN was slow. The several zips could be over 100 possilbilties.

Comment: @kris - I need to make two matches on these columns: field_id and value. How do I do that without making an alias of the table?

Comment: If you're using `IN (value1, value2, value3,...valueN)` it's no slower than `col = value1 OR col = value2 OR ...` If you're using IN for a semi-join i.e. `col IN (SELECT 1 FROM ...)`, it may actually be faster depending on storage engine/dbms etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on what you might be trying to do:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM profile_data
WHERE (field_id = 80 AND value IN ('94114', '94146', '94117'))
OR (field_id = 90 AND value = 'United States')
```

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, I didn't realize that there might be multiple rows per user. If that is the case then the above won't work. The edited exists statement in the answer above will. although you don't need to do both as subqueries:

```
 SELECT user_id FROM profile_data p1
 WHERE (field_id = 80 AND value IN ('94114', '94146', '94117'))
 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM profile_data p2 WHERE field_id = 90 AND value = 'United States' AND p1.user_id = p2.user_id)
```

Hopefully your optimizer will reduce it to the correct number of joins anyway.

As an aside, zip codes are country-specific. So this specific example is redundant, but there are plenty of valid use-cases.

Comment: postal codes are not country specific. Many many countries use a 5-digit format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code#Formats).

Comment: @kris - I need to both clauses to be true, not one OR the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
FROM profile_data data1
WHERE field_id = 80 AND value IN ('94114', '94146', '94117')
    AND EXISTS   (SELECT * 
              FROM profile_data 
              WHERE field_id = 90 
                  AND value = 'United States' 
                  AND user_id = data1.user_id)
```

Assuming you have a profile and profile data table, you could do this and avoid the distinct sort:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM profile
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM profile_data 
              WHERE field_id = 80 
                  AND value IN ('94114','94146','94117') 
                  AND user_id = profile.user_id)
AND EXISTS   (SELECT * 
              FROM profile_data 
              WHERE field_id = 90 
                  AND value = 'United States' 
                  AND user_id = profile.user_id)
```

**EDIT**
I removed one of my subqueries per Kris' solution/refinement.

Comment: Why the subqueries? If the second subquery has a row, then it will always evaluate to true... you won't get those results...just everything in profile_data that meets the first criteria. If the second subquery returns null, then you will get no results.

Comment: That's my understanding of the criteria specified by the OP. Where the ZIP code is in the range of values and the country is 'United States' Logically both must be true to satisfy his criteria. The first clause will eval true if the correlated user_id is in the list of zip codes and clause b will eval true if the correlated user_id is in the united states. When both clauses eval true, it satisfies the specified criteria.

Comment: @magicmike - There is just one table, so I need the Distinct sort. Your first example works great. And thanks for explaining why re IN.

Comment: incidentally, I'm a little baffled by the downvote since my answer was the first, it was correct even before any edits (@KrisRobison I re-formatted the SQL so you could see they were correlated subqueries and you now know that I correctly interpreted the OPs question) Kindly remove the downvote by clicking the downvote button again or, perhaps, be bold enough to comment as to why a correct and clear answer warranted a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT us_users.user_id
FROM
    (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM profile_data
        WHERE field_id = 90 AND value = 'United States'
    ) AS us_users
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM profile_data
        WHERE field_id = 80 AND value IN ('94114','94146','94117')
    ) AS zipcodes
        ON us_users.user_id = zipcodes.user_id
```